# Matplotlib exception in Django 1.11

Tags: django, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib with mpld3 library to draw a graph in django, but when I am creating a simple bar graph with the following code:

```
x=np.arange(2014, date.today().year+1, 1)
my_xticks = list(x)
educationData=np.array(getDatas(x, eType=[3, 4, 5]))
figEdu = plt.figure()
axE = figEdu.add_subplot(111)
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('#Participants')
plt.text(0.2, 0.9, '#Participants: '+str(np.sum(educationData)), ha='center', va='center', transform=axE.transAxes, fontsize=18, color='#009EF3', weight='bold')##00b3fe
plt.bar(x, educationData, color=['#009EF3'])
figHtmlEdu = mpld3.fig_to_html(figEdu)
plt.close()

figAwr = plt.figure()
axA = figEdu.add_subplot(111)
awarenessData=np.array(getDatas(x, eType=[1]))
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('#Participants')
plt.text(0.2, 0.9, '#Participants: '+str(np.sum(awarenessData)), ha='center', va='center', transform=axA.transAxes, fontsize=18, color='#FFAF27', weight='bold')##00a65a
plt.bar(x, awarenessData, color=['#FFAF27'])
figHtmlAwr = mpld3.fig_to_html(figAwr)
plt.close()

figTrn = plt.figure()
axT = figEdu.add_subplot(111)
trainingData=np.array(getDatas(x, eType=[2]))
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks)
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('#Participants')
plt.text(0.2, 0.9, '#Participants: '+str(np.sum(trainingData)), ha='center', va='center', transform=axT.transAxes, fontsize=18, color='#00E18C', weight='bold')##ffad00
plt.bar(x, trainingData, color=['#00E18C'])
figHtmlTrn = mpld3.fig_to_html(figTrn)
plt.close()
```

It's running fine for the first time but on refresh it's giving

```
    RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
```

So please help me with this exception.

Comment: I figured out. Thanks

Comment: Was there a resolution here?